# Algorithmic string in python?

Tags: python

I have a string say `a = "awxxxyyw".`

It should remove all the consecutive elements from the string and return me final string as "a".

ie in **1st iteration** `xxx` seems to be consecutive, so remove `xxx,` then string becomes `awyyw.`

**2nd iteration** removes `yy.` string becomes `aww`.

**3rd iteration** remove `ww.` returns `a`

Here is my code.

Where I'm going wrong?

```
def func(string,pointer):
    print pointer

    for i in range(pointer,len(string)):
        flag=0
        temp = i
        print temp,pointer
        try:
            while(string[i-1] == string[i]):
                print string
                i+= 1
                flag = 1
        except : break

        if flag == 0 :
            continue

        else:
            string = string[0:temp] + string[i+1:len(string)]
            func(string, temp)

    return string


string = "awxxxyyw"
print func(string,1)
```

Comment: What does your code output?

Comment: Can someone please rectify the code or can provide a new code. Thanks

Comment: @user1162512 Expected output for this: `'aaxyyza'`?

Comment: I've compiled it and what I'm getting is awxyw. How can I make it according to my needs?

Comment: When asking for help, make sure you include *as part of the question* (not the comments) what output you are currently seeing and the output you expect, based on your given input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your code to remove all consecutive repeated letters, rather than one at a time. Retaining your recursion:

```
def func(string):
    for i in range(len(string) - 1):
        if string[i] == string[i+1]:
            j = i + 1
            while j < len(string) and string[j] == string[i]:
                j += 1
            return func(string[:i] + string[j:])
    return string
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that you’re only ever removing one character at a time, and so repeated sequences will be reduced to a single character, but that single character will stick around at the end. For example, your code goes from “xxx” to “xx” to “x”, but since there’s only a single “x” left that “x” is not removed from the string. Adapt your code to remove *all* of the consecutive repeated characters and your problem will be fixed.

Comment: Well I've tried to splice the string accordingly, but that doesn't work. Can you please provide a working demo. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think this is easiest to do with an iterated regular expression substitution:

```
def remove_dups(s):
    import re
    pat = re.compile(r"(.)\1+")
    while True:
        news = pat.sub("", s)
        if s == news:
            break
        s = news
    return s

print remove_dups("awxxxyyw") # "a"
print remove_dups("aaxyyza")  # "xza"
```

Comment: I was just about to put `while s != re.sub("(.)\\1+","",s): s = re.sub("(.)\\1+","",s)`  :) but yours is better since it uses a compiled regex

Comment: Eh, most versions of Python maintain an internal cache of recently-compiled regexps, so it shouldn't matter much.  I just *like* compiling regexps in their own step :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), it allows you to group adjacent similar items:

```
from itertools import groupby

def solve(x):
    while True:
        lis = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(x)]
        print lis
        #if any item in lis has length != 1 then remove all such items
        if any(len(x) != 1 for x in lis):
           x = ''.join([''.join(x) for x in lis if len(x)==1])
        else:
            return ''.join([''.join(x) for x in lis])


s = "awxxxyyw"
print solve(s)
print 
s = 'aaacccxxxka'
print solve(s)
```

**Output:**

```
[['a'], ['w'], ['x', 'x', 'x'], ['y', 'y'], ['w']] #remove ['x', 'x', 'x'], ['y', 'y'] here
[['a'], ['w', 'w']]           #remove ['w', 'w'] here
[['a']]                       #nothing to remove, returns this as answer.
a

[['a', 'a', 'a'], ['c', 'c', 'c'], ['x', 'x', 'x'], ['k'], ['a']]
[['k'], ['a']]
ka
```

Answer (score 1):

A working demo:

```
def func(s):
    stack = ['']
    idx = 0

    while idx < len(s):
        if s[idx] == stack[-1]:
            el = s[idx]
            stack.pop()
            while idx < len(s) and s[idx] == el:
                idx += 1
        else:
            stack.append(s[idx])
            idx += 1
    return ''.join(stack)

print func('awxxxyyw')
'a'
print func('awxyw')
'awxyw'
print func('a')
'a'
print func('abcdefghijklmnoprstuvxywzzwyxvutsrponmlkjihgfedcba')
''
```